# do-release-upgrade with apt-cacher

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I've recently been trying to upgrade an Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS to the latest release.

I ran into trouble using

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

which gave me something like:

```
403 unable to download a file of that type: trusty.tar.gz.gpg
```

When I realised I was using apt-cacher. After a little searching I realised that I had to do the following on the apt-cacher server:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf
```

And to add "trusty" to list of allowed ubuntu releases.

Problem solved. Works fine for all do-release upgrades in cluster.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic: 1) It is not a question. Perhaps you meant to write an answer? 2) It is not about programming. It would be more appropriate to post this on superuser.com or askubuntu.com.

Comment: Yes, I meant to write an answer, however i was unable due to my lack of points (i think 1500 were required). I don't contribute that much to stack overflow but actually use it a lot!. Cheers

Comment: You need only **1** reputation point to be able to post answers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts

Comment: Forgot to add "only after 8 hours" to that comment. Cheers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf
```

And to add "trusty" to list of allowed ubuntu releases.

Problem solved. Works fine for all do-release upgrades in cluster.

Comment: Oh remember to "sudo service apt-cacher restart" after you make that change.